# Scrapy not crawling pages allowed by LinkExtractor

Tags: scrapy

I'm quite stuck and cannot figure out why my CrawlSpider cannot pickup and process relative links in HTML code.

Below is a cawlspider to which I can pass some params from the command line, like so:

`scrapy crawl domain_spider -a url="https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/?page=15" -s ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=0 -s AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED=0`

The spider runs and absolutely refuses to crawl the paginated pages in the list. The HTML looks like this:

```
 <a href="?page=5">&lt; Previous 20</a>
```

If I pass in params from the commans like `-a allowed="page="` then it will pickup two more pages, but it still refuses to continue.

Can anyone spot the problem in my code below?

**My CrawlSpider**:

```
def __init__(self, url=None, category='default', allowed=None, denied=None, single_page=False, **kwargs):

    self.category = category

    if allowed == '':
        allowed = None

    if denied == '':
        denied = None

    if single_page is not False and single_page != '':
        denied = '.*'

    self.start_urls = ['{}'.format(url)]
    self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(url).netloc]
    self.domain = urlparse(url).netloc
    self.rules = (
        Rule( LinkExtractor(allow=allowed, deny=denied, unique=True), callback='parse_page' ),
    )

    super(DomainSpider, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I'm glad I was able to answer this so quickly for myself.

If using CrawlSpider with Rules and you define a callback (as I have), then you must add `follow=True` to the Rule if you want it to continue to spider pages. Otherwise you will need to `yield` requests from your callback. Therefore, below is the before/after of the fix which will make CrawlSpider follow links.

**Before**

```
Rule(
    LinkExtractor(allow=allowed, deny=denied, unique=True), 
    callback='parse_page'
),
```

**After**

```
Rule( 
    LinkExtractor(allow=allowed, deny=denied, unique=True), 
    callback='parse_page', 
    follow=True
),
```